# Keycloak not returning password expired error

Tags: oauth-2.0, active-directory, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using Keycloak 3.4 with Active directory (for user federation) to protect my Api, the system is configured to use the **Resource Owner Password Credentials flow**. When a user password is expired I’m just getting **Invalid user credentials** error.

Is their any way to return the appropriate error message message, something like user ***user password expired*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, the solution was to extend **MSADUserAccountControlsMapper** to throw the appropriate exception then catch it in a subclass of **AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator**.

See : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2634